# Mathematical definition of exponent

Tags: real-numbers

What does it mean by a^b in real number system? How is it defined mathematically?
It is clear in case of exponent being an integer.
i.e., a real number **a** is multiplied **b** times where b belongs to Z
If b is a rational..say b=p/q, then a^b can be interpreted as a^(1/q) multiplied p times.
But how is it defined when b is irrational?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/582236/28900).

Comment: @Cameron Buie: thanks for the link and the answer provided in the link.

Comment: @Stefan: i tried searching before posting the question to no avail. Probably wrong choice of key words.

Comment: @vara : no problem.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You use the density of rationals in $\Bbb R$.Find a sequence $x_n\to \sqrt 2$ and $x_n<\sqrt 2$ for  every $n$. Same for a sequence $y_n\to \sqrt 2$ with $y_n>\sqrt 2$. Then ...?

Comment: @vara  it is a little trickier than what is written here .. research it some more